# how to Get Id of the record which have highest count of the boolean column from the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

i have following table in MYSQL Table name as a_ad_display with columns

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ addisplayId ║ restId  ║ clicked ║     displaytime     ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║          1  ║  20707  ║      0  ║ 2013-02-28 10:50:55 ║
║          2  ║  20708  ║      1  ║ 2013-02-28 10:55:55 ║
║          3  ║  20711  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-01 12:50:55 ║
║          4  ║  20712  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-02 01:50:55 ║
║          5  ║  20707  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-03 10:50:55 ║
║          6  ║  20708  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-03 12:50:55 ║
║          7  ║  20707  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-04 09:50:55 ║
║          8  ║  20708  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-05 10:50:55 ║
║          9  ║  20708  ║      0  ║ 2013-03-06 11:50:55 ║
║         10  ║  20707  ║      0  ║ 2013-03-06 12:50:55 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

now what i want to fetch restId which have highest concurrences of 1 in column Clicked

so from above records the 20708 restId have the highest clicked column count which is 3 ..so i want to fetch the restId with this scenario..so can anyone please guide me on that how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simpliest answer but it won't handle duplicates,

```
SELECT  restID, SUM(clicked) totalClick
FROM    a_ad_display
GROUP   BY restID
ORDER   BY totalClick DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Here is the query that will keep duplicates,

```
SELECT  restID, SUM(clicked) totalClick
FROM    a_ad_display
GROUP   BY restID
HAVING  SUM(clicked) = 
        (
            SELECT  SUM(clicked) totalClick
            FROM    a_ad_display
            GROUP   BY restID
            ORDER   BY totalClick DESC
            LIMIT   1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/008c52/6)

Comment: @BhavikKama see this example, when the total number of clicks is the same for multiple `restID` and happens to be the highest click, example [>>CLICK_HERE_FOR_DEMO<<](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7017b/2)

Comment: but if there is two restaurant with highest clicks then i want to take any one of it....so the first query will works fine in that scenario?

Comment: @BhavikKama yes because it limits the number of records return into one only.